# Deserialize multiple XML tags to single C# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have class structure as follows

```
   public class Common
    {
        public int price { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
    }
    public class SampleProduct:Common
    {
        public string sample1 { get; set; }
        public string sample2 { get; set; }
        public string sample3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I have XML file as follows

```
<ConfigData>
  <Common>
    <price>1234</price>
    <color>pink</color>    
  </Common>
  <SampleProduct>
    <sample1>new</sample1>
    <sample2>new</sample2>
    <sample3>new123</sample3>
  </SampleProduct>
</ConfigData>
```

Now I wanted to deserialize full XML data to SampleProduct object (single object).I can deserialize XML data to different object but not in a single object. Please help.

Comment: Do you create the XML file yourself or it's provided elsewhere?

Comment: you just need to create a new class name "ConfigData" and compost Common and SampleProduct  in that class. Use ConfigData than for deserialization

Comment: I have suggest an edit to modify the class structure, so are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the XML yourself Just do it like this:

```
<ConfigData>
  <SampleProduct>
    <price>1234</price>
    <color>pink</color>    
    <sample1>new</sample1>
    <sample2>new</sample2>
    <sample3>new123</sample3>
  </SampleProduct>
</ConfigData>
```

Otherwise, if you get the XML from other sources, do what Kayani suggested in his comment:

```
public class ConfigData
{
    public Common { get; set; }
    public SampleProduct { get; set; }
}
```

But don't forget that the SampleProduct created in this manner don't have "price" and "color" properties and these should be set using created Common instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution using the provided XML from you.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeserializeXml(@"C:\sample.xml");
    }
    public static void DeserializeXml(string xmlPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigData));
            using (var xmlFile = new FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var configDataOSinglebject = (ConfigData)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);
                xmlFile.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Something went wrong while interpreting the xml file: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("ConfigData")]
    public class ConfigData
    {
        [XmlElement("Common")]
        public Common Common { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SampleProduct")]
        public SampleProduct XSampleProduct { get; set; }
    }

    public class Common
    {
        [XmlElement("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleProduct
    {
        [XmlElement("sample1")]
        public string Sample1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("sample2")]
        public string Sample2 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("sample3")]
        public string Sample3 { get; set; }
    }
```

This will give you a single Object with all the elements you need.

Comment: the configDataOSinglebject  variable gives you the object. I forgot to add a comment there.